# How to unpack .tar.gz.md5 file in Linux?

Tags: linux, hashsum, file-format

I have a file called `gdac.broadinstitute.org_KIRC.Merge_Clinical.Level_1.2016012800.0.0.tar.gz.md5`

Can anyone tell how to unpack this? I haven't seen such files till now.

Thank you

Comment: The .md5 file is only for verifying the checksum of the archive. You'll need to download and extract "gdac.broadinstitute.org_KIRC.Merge_Clinical.Level_1.2016012800.0.0.tar.gz" separately. Once you have both files, you can verify the checksum: `md5sum -c gdac...tar.gz.md5`

Comment: If you see here (http://firebrowse.org/?cohort=KIRC&download_dialog=true#) In "Clinical" I downloded "Merge_Clinical" and then I got this "gdac.broadinstitute.org_KIRC.Merge_Clinical.Level_1.2016012800.0.0.tar.gz.md5"

Comment: each line seem to have two links. if you click on the `(MD5)` part, you'll get the `..tar.gz.md5`, but if you click on the left hand side, you'll get the actual archive `...tar.gz`

Comment: You need to click on the description in each link, not on “(MD5)”. [This link](http://gdac.broadinstitute.org/runs/stddata__2016_01_28/data/KIRC/20160128/gdac.broadinstitute.org_KIRC.Merge_Clinical.Level_1.2016012800.0.0.tar.gz) will download the tarball.

Comment: Oh how silly I'm...I was thinking altogether its same. This is the first time I'm using this site. Thanks a lot. I got the tar.gz now.

Answer (score 3):

The filename that you mention ends with `.md5`, which most likely means that it contains the MD5 checksum of the contents of the file that has the same name but without the `.md5` suffix.

*That* file is called `gdac.broadinstitute.org_KIRC.Merge_Clinical.Level_1.2016012800.0.0.tar.gz` and has to be downloaded separately.  Once it is downloaded, you may verify that the contents of that file is the same on your machine as on the machine where it was checksummed on by running the command

```
md5sum -c gdac.broadinstitute.org_KIRC.Merge_Clinical.Level_1.2016012800.0.0.tar.gz.md5
```

If that succeeds (it will output the name of the file followed by `OK`), you may unpack the `tar` archive with

```
tar -xzf gdac.broadinstitute.org_KIRC.Merge_Clinical.Level_1.2016012800.0.0.tar.gz
```